# File Upload dialogue doesn't include bookmarks for Home, Documents, Downloads, etc - only custom ones I made myself

Tags: nautilus, firefox, gui

When using the file manager normally to browse files, I can see both the **Places** (which includes default bookmarks for Home, Documents, and others), and **Bookmarks** - which includes my custom bookmarks, which I can also see when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

It's easy and quick to navigate around.

However, when using the file manager to upload files in Firefox - it has a different layout, and doesn't include the **Places** section, only my custom bookmarks. That makes it harder to navigate since I almost always want to upload from there.

Here's how that looks like:

[image]

Is it possible to include the **Places** section in the file upload dialogue in Firefox?